# Ist „wessen bedarfst du“ richtig?

Tags: verb, genitive

Das Verb *bedürfen* hat ein Genitivobjekt. Dann sollte man eigentlich eine Frage mit solchem Objekt mit *wessen* stellen können, etwa:

> Wessen zusätzlicher Voraussetzungen bedürften die neuen Gesetze?

Ist *wessen* geläufig für *bedürfen*?

Comment: Allgemein ist _bedürfen_ nicht mehr sehr gebräuchlich, sicherlich gerade weil es mit Genitiv konstruiert wird (oder wurde).

Comment: @chirlu: Solche Aussagen bedürfen eines Belegs. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bed%C3%BCrfen&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbed%C3%BCrfen%3B%2Cc0 "nicht sehr gebräuchlich" ist eine sehr vage Behauptung, dass dies am Genetiv liege eine gewagte.

Comment: @user unknown: Laut Duden ist das Wort "gehoben", ein gehobener Ausdruck für "kommt in Alltagssprache nicht vor". Außerdem sind die angegebenen Kollokationen (Zustimmung, Genehmigung, Schriftform usw.) vorwiegend juristisch.

Comment: Und juristische Texte sind nicht sehr gebräuchlich? Unter Juristen wohl schon, und damit womöglich in Vertragstexten. Das unterstreicht v.a. wie vage "nicht mehr sehr gebräuchlich" ist. Der Graph zeigt ja einen Abfall auf ca. ein Drittel seit dem Maximum um 1820. Ich schätze aber, dass sich die Zahl der Schriftstücke seit dem mehr als verdreifacht hat, dass also das Wort heute weit öfter benutzt wird als 1820.

Comment: @user unknown: Ich formuliere es anders. Wenn du einkaufen gehen willst und anderen anbietest, ihnen etwas mitzubringen, wirst du mit der Frage _Wessen bedarfst du?_ in jedem Fall Aufsehen erregen; vielleicht wirst du Heiterkeit ernten, möglicherweise auch Unverständnis, abhängig vom Bildungsgrad des Gefragten.

Comment: @chirlu: Dein Kommentar bedarf einer Reaktion die hiermit erbracht ist. Das Ragout bedarf einer Note Chilie. Kinder bedürfen der Zuwendung.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Wessen* ist gewissermaßen die Genitiv-Form der Fragewörter *wer* bzw. *was*. Man kann also fragen:

> Wessen bedürfen die neuen Gesetze?

Im Beispiel gibt es aber noch ein Substantiv (Voraussetzungen), auf das sich das Fragewort bezieht. Dann können wir nicht *wer* oder *was* fragen. Vergleiche die folgenden Sätze:

> *Was* ist gegeben?
>
> *Welche* Voraussetzungen sind gegeben?

Wir brauchen hier also die Genitivform von *welche* und fragen somit:

> Welcher Voraussetzungen bedürfen die neuen Gesetze?

Nachtrag: Die Formulierung *Wessen Voraussetzungen …* wäre grammatisch auch möglich, hätte aber eine andere Bedeutung. Damit würde man fragen, zu wem die Voraussetzungen gehören, um die es geht. In diesem Fall dürfte diese Frage wenig Sinn ergeben.